# IE9 error '$'is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer-9

```
<!--[if lte IE 9]><html class="lte9"><![endif]--><!--[if gt IE 9]><html><![endif]-->
<!--[if !IE]><!-->
<html>
<!--<![endif]-->
    blah blah

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="{{ asset('js/mypage.js') }}" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

[image]

when I load my page, IE9 brings error like this `'$' is not defined`.
How can I solve this error?

+++ mypage.js

```
$(function(){

//when load page,
//ie9 i tag not moving.

$(window).load(function() {     

    $('div.mask').hide();   

});

// when click about , willshow will show.

//for not IE 9
if (!$('html').hasClass('lte9')) {

    var about = $('ul.about > li > span.activebtn');
    var willshow = $('div.willshow');

    about.on('click',function(){

        willshow.toggleClass('active');

        about.html(function(){

            if ($(willshow).hasClass('active')) {
                return 'close';
            }
            return 'about';
        });

    });

}

// because CSS3 not working in IE9.
if($('html').hasClass('lte9')) {

    about.click(function(){

        willshow.animate({
            'left': '0'
        }, 500);

        about.html(function(){

            if (willshow.hasClass('active')) {
                return 'close';
                about.click(function(){
                    willshow.animate({
                        'left': '-100%'
                    }, 500);
                });
            }
            return 'about';

        });

    });

}
});
```

check my js file plz. beacause IE9 not support css3, I just want to make animate function in place of CSS3. It work successfully in chrome.

Comment: What you have should (and does) work absolutely fine. Are you sure you're not calling jQuery's `noConflict()` method somewhere, or calling jQuery before it has been loaded in the page?

Comment: i don't understand the text in the image.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I don't use `noConflct()` anywhere.

Comment: @KevinKloet that means will you debug this page? blah blah , and text in box means line: 1 , error : '$' is not defined

Comment: Does it work fine with other browsers? like IE10 or 11? and is your website online so we can take a look into the live version?

Comment: Try put in type="text/javascript" in script tag which loads jquery.

Comment: @modernator it's same .

Comment: @SasiJoOoOon I checked in IE9, chrome yet. not testing IE10 or IE11. And you can't see my live page. sry

Comment: Well can you share your javascripts functions? there might be a syntax error in one of them since including jquery itself alone will not trigger an error.

Comment: @SasiJoOoOon I edit mine. check plz

Comment: I tried the code in firefox,chrome, IE10 and IE 11. all worked fine for me.

Comment: Oh thank you checking for me.